# Setting BlobHttpHeaders seems to 'corrupt' my image upload

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am uploading a PNG image to local blob storage using Docker/Azurite.

The file on my drive is 167.08 KiB. When I upload the file without setting the headers, it's also 167.08 KiB, however the Content Type is set to `application/octet-stream` and is therefore not served correctly.

Easy enough fix, I thought. I set the Content Type header to `image/png` - but now the blob is only 167.06 KiB, and the file seems "corrupted". It cannot be viewed or opened by any image editor.

Can someone advise? Code below.

**167.06 KiB, file is invalid:**

```
public async Task<Uri> Upload(string container, string destination, MemoryStream stream)
{
  stream.Position = 0;
  var blob = this.Blob(container, destination);

  var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders() { ContentType = "image/png" };
  var uploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions() { HttpHeaders = headers };

  await blob.UploadAsync(stream, uploadOptions);
  return blob.Uri;
}
```

**167.08 KiB, file has incorrect Content Type:**

```
public async Task<Uri> Upload(string container, string destination, MemoryStream stream)
{
  stream.Position = 0;
  var blob = this.Blob(container, destination);
  await blob.UploadAsync(stream);
  return blob.Uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this, I reset the stream position immediately before uploading, and that resolved the issues.

```
public async Task<Uri> Upload(string container, string destination, MemoryStream stream)
{
  //stream.Position = 0;    <------ THIS NEEDS TO BE MOVED...
  var blob = this.Blob(container, destination);

  var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders() { ContentType = "image/png" };
  var uploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions() { HttpHeaders = headers };

  stream.Position = 0;  // <------- HERE
  await blob.UploadAsync(stream, uploadOptions);
  return blob.Uri;
}
```